# How to factor polynomial $\:f(x)=1+x^2+x^4,\:\:f\in \:Z_3\left [x\right]$

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, factorial

I have been trying to solve the following polynomial factoring:
$$
f(x) = 1 + x^2 + x^4,\quad f∈Z_3[x]
$$
But I am stuck with:
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 1 - 2x^2 + x^4 \\
&= (x^2 -1)^2 \\
&= x^2 -1 \\
&= (x + 1)(x - 1)
\end{align}
$$

How should I progress pass this?

Comment: How do you figure that $(x^2-1)^2=x^2-1$? These polynomials do not even have the same degree...

Comment: You were fine at $(x^2-1)^2$; you could factor this further by noting $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ for a final factorization of $(x-1)^2 (x+1)^2$, which is what **Servaes** has used. Alternatively, you could observe again that $-1 = 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, so that the final factorization is $(x+1)^2 (x+2)^2$.

Comment: I think this is the part where I got it wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $(1+x^2+x^4)(1-x^2)=(1-x^6)$ hence
$$ f(x) = (1-x+x^2)(1+x+x^2) = \Phi_3(x)\,\Phi_6(x) $$
and over $\mathbb{F}_3$
$$ f(x) = (1+2x+x^2)(1-2x+x^2) = (1+x)^2 (1-x)^2 $$
completely splits. If $p$ is a prime $\geq 5$ and $h$ is the least integer such that $6\mid (p^h-1)$,
 $f(x)$ completely splits over $\mathbb{F}_{p^h}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that we are working over $\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z}$, clearly $1$ and $-1$ are roots of the polynomial, so long division by $(x-1)(x+1)=x^2-1$ shows that
$$x^4+x^2+1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+2)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2-1)=(x-1)^2(x+1)^2.$$

Comment: I am new to this term Z/3Z. Can you please help me about what it is?